# Algebraic Groups, dual numbers and differentials

Tags: algebraic-groups, differential, tangent-bundle

I was looking for a method to compute the explicit differential of a regular map between algebraic groups. More precisely if $X$ is a sub-variety in an algebraic group $G$ (say over a finite field $k$), I'd like to compute the differential of the map
\begin{align}
\phi:X\times X&\longrightarrow G\\
(x_1,x_2)&\longmapsto (x_1*x_2),
\end{align}
where * is the group low.

I found this related question, "[What is the differential of a translation map on an algebraic group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957343/what-is-the-differential-of-a-translation-map-on-an-algebraic-group)" but I'm a bit confused about the re-interpretation of the tangent bundle and the dual numbers. Can someone explain me a bit more what is going on?

Thank you very much!